# System crashing on snap apparmor brave error

Tags: snap, crash, apparmor, brave

Relevant passage from syslog:

```
Jun 29 18:06:28 noah-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx NetworkManager[1023]: <info>  [1688076388.3763] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECT
ED_SITE\
Jun 29 18:06:28 noah-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx dbus-daemon[1021]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatc
her' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.4' (uid=0 pid=1023 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label=
"unconfined")\
Jun 29 18:06:28 noah-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...\
Jun 29 18:06:28 noah-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx dbus-daemon[1021]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'\
Jun 29 18:06:28 noah-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.\
Jun 29 18:06:28 noah-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx NetworkManager[1023]: <info>  [1688076388.4875] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECT
ED_GLOBAL\
Jun 29 18:06:38 noah-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.\
Jun 29 18:07:49 noah-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx kernel: [ 1352.964282] audit: type=1400 audit(1688076469.219:238): apparmor="DENIED" operati
on="open" profile="snap.brave.brave" name="/proc/pressure/cpu" pid=3448 comm="ThreadPoolForeg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 o
uid=0\
Jun 29 18:07:49 noah-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx kernel: [ 1352.964323] audit: type=1400 audit(1688076469.219:239): apparmor="DENIED" operati
on="open" profile="snap.brave.brave" name="/proc/pressure/io" pid=3448 comm="ThreadPoolForeg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0\
Jun 29 18:07:49 noah-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx kernel: [ 1352.964342] audit: type=1400 audit(1688076469.219:240): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.brave.brave" name="/proc/pressure/memory" pid=3448 comm="ThreadPoolForeg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0\
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
```

Then the computer crashed. Here are the computer specs.

- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.2
- Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-76-generic
- Architecture: x86-64
- Hardware vendor: HP hardware model: HP Pavilion Laptop 15-cs0xxx

How can this be stopped, o at least what is causing this?

Comment: Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS               
          Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-76-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: HP
  Hardware Model: HP Pavilion Laptop 15-cs0xxx
Right, here is the computer and that 7 year old bug was the closest thing I could find on my own. Since I don't think that's the problem I came here.

Comment: Do you need help to file a proper bug report? ...or what is the question?

Comment: This isn't a kernel bug, this is a isolation stuff - and the snap sandboxing is doing its job.  Brave and other applicatoins don't *need* access to CPU and IO datasets and stuff, and that's not a kernel *bug* that's just an audit alert from apparmor.